# SSE addition and conversion

Tags: c++, sse

Here's the thing, how can I add two unsigned char arrays and store the result in an unsigned short array by using SSE. Can anyone give me some help or hint. This is what I have done so far. I just don't know where the error is..need some help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<intrin.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<emmintrin.h>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

void sse_add(unsigned char * input1, unsigned char *input2, unsigned short  *output, const int N)
{   

unsigned char *op3 = new unsigned char[N];
unsigned char *op4 = new unsigned char[N];

__m128i *sse_op3 = (__m128i*)op3;
__m128i *sse_op4 = (__m128i*)op4;
__m128i *sse_result = (__m128i*)output;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 16)
{
     __m128i src = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)input1);
     __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
     __m128i higher = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(src, zero);
     __m128i lower = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(src, zero);

     _mm_storeu_si128(sse_op3, lower);
     sse_op3 = sse_op3 + 1;
     _mm_storeu_si128(sse_op3, higher);
     sse_op3 = sse_op3 + 1;
    input1 = input1 + 16;

}

for (int j = 0; j < N; j = j + 16)
{
     __m128i src1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)input2);
     __m128i zero1 = _mm_setzero_si128();
     __m128i higher1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(src1, zero1);
     __m128i lower1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(src1, zero1);

    _mm_storeu_si128(sse_op4, lower1);
    sse_op4 = sse_op4 + 1;
    _mm_storeu_si128(sse_op4, higher1);
    sse_op4 = sse_op4 + 1;
    input2 = input2 + 16;

}

__m128i *sse_op3_new = (__m128i*)op3;
__m128i *sse_op4_new = (__m128i*)op4;

for (int y = 0; y < N; y = y + 8)
{
    *sse_result = _mm_adds_epi16(*sse_op3_new, *sse_op4_new);
    sse_result = sse_result + 1;
    sse_op3_new = sse_op3_new + 1;
    sse_op4_new = sse_op4_new + 1;
}

}

void C_add(unsigned char * input1, unsigned char *input2, unsigned short *output, int N)
{
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    output[i] = (unsigned short)input1[i] + (unsigned short)input2[i];

}



int main()
{
int n = 1023;
unsigned char *p0 = new unsigned char[n];
unsigned char *p1 = new unsigned char[n];
unsigned short *p21 = new unsigned short[n];
unsigned short *p22 = new unsigned short[n];
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    p21[j] = rand() % 256;
    p22[j] = rand() % 256;
}

C_add(p0, p1, p22, n);
cout << "C_add finished!" << endl;
sse_add(p0, p1, p21, n);
cout << "sse_add finished!" << endl;

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    if (p21[j] != p22[j])
    {
        cout << "diff!!!!!@@@@@@@" << endl;
    }
}
//system("pause");

delete[] p0;
delete[] p1;
delete[] p21;
delete[] p22;
return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming everything is aligned to `_Alignof(__m128i)` and the size of the array is a multiple of `sizeof(__m128i)`, something like this should work:

```
void addw(size_t size, uint16_t res[size], uint8_t a[size], uint8_t b[size]) {
  __m128i* r = (__m128i*) res;
  __m128i* ap = (__m128i*) a;
  __m128i* bp = (__m128i*) b;

  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < (size / sizeof(__m128i)) ; i++) {
    r[(i * 2)]     = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_cvtepu8_epi16(ap[i]), _mm_cvtepu8_epi16(bp[i]));
    r[(i * 2) + 1] = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_cvtepu8_epi16(_mm_srli_si128(ap[i], 8)), _mm_cvtepu8_epi16(_mm_srli_si128(bp[i], 8)));
  }
}
```

FWIW, NEON would be a bit simpler (using `vaddl_u8` and `vaddl_high_u8`).

If you're dealing with unaligned data you can use `_mm_loadu_si128`/`_mm_storeu_si128`.  If size isn't a multiple of 16 you'll just have to do the remainder without SSE.

Note that this may be something your compiler can do automatically (I haven't checked).  You may want to try something like this:

```
#pragma omp simd
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
  res[i] = ((uint16_t) a[i]) + ((uint16_t) b[i]);
}
```

That uses OpenMP 4, but there is also Cilk++ (`#pragma simd`), clang (`#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)`), gcc (`#pragma GCC ivdep`), or you could just hope the compiler is smart enough without the pragma hint.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have posted my code...there is an error(breakpoint) when I run it, really confused..